# How to identify low pass, bandpass, band reject, high pass filter etc from given $|H(e^{j\omega})|$?

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, digital-filters

**1) How is this a low pass filter?**

$0.99 \leq |H(e^{j\omega})|\leq1.01 {\rm\ for\ } 0\leq|\omega|\leq0.19\pi$

$|H(e^{j\omega}\;)|\leq0.01{\rm\ for\ } 0.21\pi\leq|\omega|\leq\pi$

**2) What kind of filter is this? Low pass, high pass, band pass, band reject or what?**
$0.99 \leq |H(e^{j\omega})|\leq1.01 {\rm\ for\ }  0\geq|\omega|\geq0.19\pi$

$|H(e^{j\omega}\;)|\leq0.01{\rm\ for\ } 0.21\pi\leq|\omega|\leq\pi$

I am really confused on how to identify if a filter is high pass, band pass, low pass, band reject from given specifications. Can you make me understand this concepts?

Comment: If you have trouble reading the math, why don't you just draw it ? It becomes blatantly obvious then.

Comment: Yeah I got it now(the first one).  Can you tell me about the second question? How can sth be lesser than 0 yet greater than $0.19\pi$, is that second question wrong?

Comment: The second one is clearly a typo, that's pretty obvious.

Comment: oh thanks a lot. i was geting confused due to that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the trick-: I just found it out somewhere
[image]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I think it is easy and self explanatory to understand. So I didn't explain it.  For eg-: LPF means high for -wc to wc, otherwise 0. And so on. It is very intiutive to understand.